# What is the design pattern that allows you to dynamically add attributes to an object model without modifying db entities or DAL?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

For a forthcoming project we have looked at things CMS/EMS tools that have a form/page authoring component where authors can dynamically add new input fields at will, without needing to update database entities or the DAL.

I'm looking for the design patter to accomplish this with .Net, C# and SQL Server.

**UPDATE**

An additional requirement is to be able to tag/categorize additional attributes so we can filter them for display/use as needed.

Comment: I've used an EAV model in the past to solve this kind of problem. It's basically a way of letting the data describe your schema. From Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model

Comment: BTW, I won't use this as an answer because I've seen some people that know more about databases than me discouraging the use of EAV..

Comment: Don't use EAV. If all you have is unstructured data, you don't want to go for SQL, go for MongoDB or something like that.

Comment: @asemprini87 and if I have 100 regular tables and just one with unstructured data?

Comment: *** For those of you who wish to down-vote, why not provide a supporting reason? ***

Comment: EAV is a double edged sword. Used appropriately it a very flexible and useful pattern. But it can be abused and things suddenly go horribly wrong. This is one of my favorite stories of EAV gone horribly wrong. https://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/ You can also look at Sharepoint and many other examples where it was used when needed to extend a normalized design effectively.

Comment: There is a pandemic on this site of people who just like to click the downvote button and disappear into the shadows. It is the nature of this site but a bit strange. Seemed like a pretty reasonable question to me since you knew about the pattern but couldn't figure out the name. Without the name it would be difficult to search for. Of course EAV tends to bring out a lot of opinion and emotion but you didn't ask anything other than the name.

Comment: @Evk Then save that data as JSON or XML in a table (depending what version or database engine you are using).